# First UIBarButton disappears when second one is added

Tags: ios

I am working on ios Bar Button icon where I have to display UIsegmented control with two UIBarButton icon on the right site but when I try to add second button using interface builder  the first added button get disappears

This is how the view is added:
View->Navigation Bar->Navigation Item-> BarButton Item-> Button

Can anyone help me to find the possible solution

Answer (score 1):

```
UIBarButtonItem *item1=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(firstSelector)];

UIBarButtonItem *item2=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(secondSelector)];

NSArray *items=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:item1,item2, nil];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems=items;
```